# Associantion of a jpg by command line fails

Tags: windows, command-line, file-association

I'm trying to associate files by command line.

I could associate `.rar` file by this command

```
assoc .rar=rarfile
ftype rarfile=%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\bin\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe x -ad "%1"
```

But it fails with `.jpg`.
I skipped `assoc` step, because it is already associated to `jpegfile`.

```
ftype jpegfile=%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\bin\zeed0814\zeed.exe "%1"
```

There are two problem after that.

First problem, default Windows Image viewer stays as the default associated program.

Second problem, even if I choose `zeed` from context menu `run by a program`, windows image viewer is launched.

I'm sure path of executable file `zeed` is correct.

Why is this not working? How can I fix this?